# Modify SObjectField Label in apex code

Tags: apex, custom-field

I have my custom field available here from a standard object Product2:

```
Schema.Product2.fields.Tier1__c
```

The field Name is 'Tier1' and its current field label is 'Tier1' I would like to update the label, how can I do that ?

```
setLabel('test')  ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Salesforce Metadata API in order to edit field labels. If you want to do this from Apex, you'll need to use a library like [FinancialForce's apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

Comment: This is a correct answer but I haven't used that solution because the library had some failing tests and the code coverage wasn't high enough. I changed my plan and I'm loading my data directly in a visualforce page by pulling the REST api I'm using.